# Using Private Server (Located at Office) in Domain

Tags: hosting

My Client is asking for redirection of the domain to their private server with public IP and use the control panel for sub domains and etc...

Is it possible or not, if yes what is the best approach.

Thanks

Comment: I'm really sorry, Core, but I don't get the question.  Could you perhaps give us a clearer *example* of what you're trying to do, preferably with the actual domain name in question?

Comment: Clearly not professional sysadmin topic, I suggest a migration to superuser.com .

Comment: Core: maybe you could learn the basics of the basics of the basics of the primal things like domain, dns, http redirecting, routing, etc. Your problem is that you are total beginner and not an IT problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the server of your client has a public (dynamic?) IP address, you need to sign up with a dyndns service like [no-ip](http://www.noip.com) or [dyn](http://dyn.com).

Since the IP address is likely to change every day, a (sub-)domain has to be pointed to that IP everytime it changes. The dyndns service does that for you. All you have to do is ping the service once the IP address changed, so the service knows the new one and can change the domain records.

Most dyndns services have premium features, that can handle custom (sub-)domains.